# How the web services works?

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, xcode, web-services

I have some questions on webservices,
when we call the web service with particular URL what happened?
I have the A-Z Groups in my iphone, when user click on A then I want to display the data which is started from A. In the web service I Have only one Soap Action... How to filter the whole web service data on server side? I want only data according to the Alphabet only. I don't want any other data at that time. I don't want to save All the data in my iPhone when calling the web service..

Please give me Perfect Answer for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities :

Either you decide to filter on client side, meaning recovering all data from WS and the filter only what you want to use.

Or you decide to filter on server side. For that, you can modidify your current WS with new parameters (like letters you want to filter), or you can also add a new WS which does that.

If I were you, I would keep the current WS like that and create a second WS with restrictive parameters.

Comment: sufficient answer to an obtuse question +1